Add default signature
everyone!
I've been having trouble with a macro I've been developing, I tried everything and still haven't found the answer, hope anyone can help me with this. Here's my code;
Sub Code()
    Dim OutApp As New Outlook.Application
        Dim OutMail As MailItem, signature As String
        Dim OMail As Object
        Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
       For r = 2 To lr
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With OutMail
    End With
    signature = OMail.Body
    With OutMail
        .To = Range("C" & r).Value
        '.CC = ""
        .Subject = Range("D" & r).Value
        bodyheader = "Dear " & Range("B" & r).Value & ","
        bodymain = Range("E2").Value
        .Body = bodyheader & vbLf & vbLf & bodymain & signature
      'Body = .HTMLBody
    
        .Attachments.Add Range("F2").Value
        
        .Attachments.Add Range("G2").Value
        
        .Attachments.Add Range("H" & r).Value
        
        .Display
    
        '.Send
       
        End With
        
    Next r
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

Please let me know any other tips or tricks to get the correct solution for it.
